# How to install LogMeIn on Ubuntu Linux 10.04

Tags: remote-access

I am beginning to use the remote access tool, LogMeIn, and I love it.  I am currently managing a Windows 2003 server with LogMeIn, and now I would like to add another server which is a Ubuntu Linux 10.04.

At the LogMeIn website they appear to have some beta versions of their client software available for Linux, but it says that they are command line only and I am not familiar with how to install them.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can install the client software for LogMeIn on this Ubuntu Linux 10.04 machine?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to not use logmein to manage a server and to just go with a secure shell server running for remote access purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pougnet, but could you recommend a good tool to use as a "secure shell server" for running remote access purposes? I want to follow your suggestion, but don't know how. Thanks.

Comment: Install OPENSSH.  Follow the excellent tutorial located at https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/openssh-server.html

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a matter of downloading and running (Ubuntu Software Center) the .deb file from the labs [page](https://secure.logmein.com/labs).

I too use it in Windows and would love to see it in action on Linux.  I will try it tomorrow on my Ubuntu 10.10 box

Comment: I downloaded and installed it on my 10.10 server.  Then from a root terminal or using sudo I ran: hamachi login <ligmeinaccount> followed by hamachi attach <ligmeinaccount>.  I then logged into my LogMeIn account and went to the "Join Requests" page to accept the request.  All this adds it to the account where it can join your networks.  But it does not give you the ability to remotely control the machine.  You may have to do what I do and remote control a Windows box on your network and then VNC into your Ubuntu server

Comment: Since the Windows box connection is encrypted it matters not that the VNC connection is not secure since its traffic is only over your local network not the internet.